# How to Autostart Music Player Daemon (MPD) so music will play as soon as the Pi is powered on?

Tags: raspbian, pi-b+, mpd

I am making an internet radio using a raspberry pi B+.  I am using Music Player Daemon (MPD) and MPC.  I have it mostly working as expected but I can not figure out how to get MPD to autostart when I turn on the pi.  If I have MPD running and I do

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

the pi will restart with it playing but if it turns off when MPD is not playing then I will have to remote into it and

```
mpc play
```

to get the music to start.  I have tried using rc.local with

```
 /etc/init.d/mpd start
```

but that didn't work.

I am using the latest version of rasbian released in November 2018.  The MPD service is enabled and running when it is powered on.

Comment: Have you checked this [raspberry forums thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=133889)?

Comment: @GramThanos maybe not the best link to share. It's from 2016 and I see references to Wheezy and other fairly old stuff

Comment: @Dirk I don't think it is a rasbian problem, and some debugging suggestions on that thread looks solid.

Comment: I did read that thread but there were things it talked about which were over my head.  Symlinks.  Although I did check the status using 'service mpd status' and the service is running.  I think that thread was more about the MPD service not running.

Answer (score 2):

Use `systemd` instead of `rc.local`

```
$ sudo systemctl enable mpd
...
$ sudo systemctl start mpd  
...
```

This will cause `mpd` to start immediately, and be started during the boot process on each successive reboot.

Comment: That needs Raspbian Stretch - which includes /lib/systemd/system/mpd.service to get mpd started. Not sure that was in Jessie (and I don't have any system left running Jessie).

Comment: @Dougie: ? Huh? OP said, "I am using the latest version of rasbian released in November 2018"